# Как вывести php код текстом

Tags: php

Чтобы он не исполнялся, а был текстом в php странице..

Comment: @Eugene Smiths, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если память не изменяет, то это можно сделать отключить php на apache. И открыть php файл.

Или же убрать теги <?php и ?> в начале и в конце

Вам для чего вообще?

Самый лучший вариант

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents(__FILE__));
echo '</pre>';
```

Вариант с подсветкой кода

```
highlight_string(file_get_contents(__FILE__));
```

ну или так

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
if ($f = fopen(__FILE__, 'r')) {
    fpassthru($f);
    fclose($f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая функция:

```
echo htmlentities($var);
```